# Create a list of sequential monthly dates in PHP given initial date and quantity

Tags: php, list, date, datetime, sequential

I'm working on a little payments system and must generate a list of payment days (monthly) given an initial date and number of payments. So, for example:

Given:

> startday: 2015/06/22
>   qtty: 6

I should get the day from initial date (22) and generate a list of 6 sequential monthly dates:

- 2015/06/22 (if initial date should be included, and is > than today)
- 2015/07/22
- 2015/08/24
- 2015/09/22
- 2015/10/22
- 2015/11/23

As you can see, generated dates should not be weekends (sat/dom) and -if possible- nor holidays

Is there any function that could help me achieve this? TIA

Comment: What should next month dates be, if startday is `2015/01/31` ?

Comment: @Glavić I will verify that the startday is always greater than today, but in case the date can be entered, 2015/01/31 is saturday so should not be possible also. In case it could be entered anyways, the list should be: 2015/01/31, 2015/02/27, 2015/03/30, 2015/04/30, 2015/05/29 and so on (checking next dates don't fall on sat/dom days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might do what you want, including holidays:

```php
<?php

$startday = strtotime("2015/08/24");
$qtty = 5;

// Add as many holidays as desired.
$holidays = array();
$holidays[] = "4 Jul"; 
$holidays[] = "25 Dec";


for( $i = 0; $i < $qtty; $i++ ) {
    $next_month = strtotime("+".$i." month", $startday); // Also works with "+ 30 days"
    while( in_array(date("d M", $next_month), $holidays)) { // Is holiday
        $next_month = strtotime("+ 1 day", $next_month);

        if( date("N", $next_month) > 5 ) { // Is weekend
            $next_month = strtotime("next Monday", $next_month); // or "previous Friday"
        }
   }
    echo(date( "Y-m-d", $next_month) . '</br>');
}

?>
```

Will echo

```
2015-08-25
2015-09-25
2015-10-26 // Because of weekend
2015-11-25
2015-12-28 // Because of Christmas and weekend
```

And with a start date of 2015/10/31 the output will be:

```
2015-11-02 // Because of weekend
2015-12-01 // Because the 31st of Nov is the 1st of Dec
2015-12-31
2016-02-01 // Because the weekend
2016-03-02 // Because the 31st of Feb is the 2st of Mars (as 2016 is leep year)
```

As a good extra tips, depending on how you want to solve the 31st of Jan problem, if you want the last of each month, you can always use the following:

```
$first_of_the_month = strtotime(date("Y-m-1", $startday));
$next_month = strtotime("+ 1 month", $first_of_the_month);
$last_of_the_month = date("Y-m-t", $next_month);
echo($last_of_the_month); // 2015-09-30
```

Comment: Code works perfect, but you have to take the if clause out from the while or it won't check weekends. Thanks @Krycke